# Running OpenFire as a different user

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu-10.04, users, openfire

I have a Ubuntu 10.4 system on which I'm running OpenFire but it currently runs as root. How can I make Openfire run as a different user?

Thanks

Comment: How did you do the install?  I don't have an OpenFire device handy to look, but if I remember correctly, the .deb installation created a user for the service.

Answer (score 1):

I restart openfire nightly with a cron, so you should also be able to use this:

```
sudo -u other_username /home/openfire/bin/openfire start
```

Answer (score -1):

Not completely sure about OpenFire, however something like `su user openfire` should work.

Comment: Openfire is a chat server, you don't start something like that manually.